# OpenCV Windows - The library is compiled without QT support in function displayOverlay

Tags: qt, opencv, highgui

I'm getting the following error:

```
python run.py
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The library is compiled without QT support) in displayOverlay, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 528
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 203, in <module>
    change_img_index(0)
  File "run.py", line 25, in change_img_index
    "" + str(last_img_index), 1000)
cv2.error: /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:528: error: (-213) The library is compiled without QT support in function displayOverlay
```

If I had installed via cmake I think I would only need to make sure the `WITH_QT` flag is set to `WITH_QT=ON` and recompile (as referenced [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/60249/the-library-is-compiled-without-qt-support-in-function-displayoverlay/)) but what if I installed using the **pre-built libraries**?

Comment: You should put your CMake output.

Comment: @Aram I installed using the pre-built packages, first method here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html So I didn't use cmake

Comment: Ok I guess I have to re-install everything and this time with cmake, right?

Comment: Oh I misread as you had used the flag WITH_QT=ON, yes its most likely the prebuilts don't use qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to this page because I had the same problem. I was having it trying to run `python run.py` for [this](https://github.com/Cartucho/yolo-boundingbox-labeler-GUI) Github project.

I actually found the solution to the problem on the project's page, in [this issue's thread](https://github.com/Cartucho/yolo-boundingbox-labeler-GUI/issues/2). Following the instructions provided by MattKleinsmith about installing opencv-python using:

`pip install opencv-python`

the script was able to run immediately.

Comment: And by the way, I know you are the project's author and opened this question to help a user solving a similar issue :)